# Convert decimal to locale fails using datatool in combination with tabularray

Tags: siunitx, tabularray, datatool

I have this rather complex code which produces several tables at the end.
The problem currently is the locale setting of the last table. This uses commands from `datatool` to calculate the sum of several positions.
In the individual tables (e.g. `\excTable{EarlyCareer}` and `\excTable{Collaboration}`) everythig looks like expected. But using the command `\DTLsumcolumn` or  `\DTLsumforkeys` changes the locale - so decimal markers are interpreted false.
Using   `\DTLsumcolumn{TotalStructuralMeasures}{totalsum}{\excSumTotalStructuralMeasures}` outside of the `tblr`environment, everything is fine.

I cannot use `\DTLdecimaltolocale` as well, since this causes a compiling error:

```
! Package siunitx Error: Invalid number '35,,000'.

For immediate help type H <return>.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.242 \excTable{TotalStructuralMeasures}
```

Here is the complete MWE:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage{datatool,xstring}
\usepackage{xkeyval}

\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{booktabs}
\PassOptionsToPackage{
  mode =  match,
  propagate-math-font = true,
  reset-math-version = false,
  reset-text-family = false,
  reset-text-series = false,
  reset-text-shape  = false,
  text-family-to-math = true,
  text-series-to-math = true,
  tight-spacing = true,
  group-minimum-digits = 4, % --> 1.234 instead of 1234
  group-separator = {,},% for "12.345" instead of "12 345" %
  %table-format = 6,
  table-alignment-mode = format,
  %table-auto-round,
  locale=UK,
}{siunitx}
\UseTblrLibrary{siunitx}

\sisetup{output-decimal-marker={.}} % Neue Zeile hinzugefügt

\providecommand\excDB{}
\makeatletter
\define@key{funding}{category}{\DTLnewdbentry{\excDB}{category}{#1}}
\define@key{funding}{fundingYear1}{\DTLnewdbentry{\excDB}{fundingYear1}{#1}}
\define@key{funding}{fundingYear2}{\DTLnewdbentry{\excDB}{fundingYear2}{#1}}
\define@key{funding}{fundingYear3}{\DTLnewdbentry{\excDB}{fundingYear3}{#1}}
\define@key{funding}{fundingYear4}{\DTLnewdbentry{\excDB}{fundingYear4}{#1}}
\define@key{funding}{fundingYear5}{\DTLnewdbentry{\excDB}{fundingYear5}{#1}}
\define@key{funding}{fundingYear6}{\DTLnewdbentry{\excDB}{fundingYear6}{#1}}
\define@key{funding}{fundingYear7}{\DTLnewdbentry{\excDB}{fundingYear7}{#1}}
\define@key{funding}{totalsum}{\DTLnewdbentry{\excDB}{totalsum}{#1}}
\makeatother

\NewDocumentCommand{\excEntry}{ m o m }{%
  % #1 name of the database into which the values are stored
  % #2 name of the keys
  % #3 part of the key-values
  \def\excDB{#1}%
  \DTLifdbexists{\excDB}{}{\DTLnewdb{\excDB}}%
  \DTLnewrow{\excDB}%
  \IfNoValueTF{#2}{\setkeys{#1}{#3}}{\setkeys{#2}{#3}}%
}


\NewDocumentCommand{\tmpDTLifdbexists}{mmm}{%
  \DTLifdbexists{#2}
  {\DTLsumforkeys{#2}{%
      fundingYear1,%
      fundingYear2,%
      fundingYear3,%
      fundingYear4,%
      fundingYear5,%
      fundingYear6,%
      fundingYear7%
    }{#3}%
    \excEntry{#1}[funding]{%
      category={#2},
      totalsum={#3}%
    }}%yes
  {}%no
}

\makeatletter
\NewDocumentCommand{\excTotalStructuralMeasuresTable}{}{%
  \def\tblrbody{}%
  \tmpDTLifdbexists{TotalStructuralMeasures}{EarlyCareer}{\EarlyCareer}%
  \tmpDTLifdbexists{TotalStructuralMeasures}{Collaboration}{\Collaboration}%
  \DTLforeach{TotalStructuralMeasures}{%
    \category      =category,%
    \totalsum      =totalsum%
  }{%
    %%\DTLdecimaltolocale{\totalsum}{\totalsum}% try to convert . to ,
    \protected@edef\tblrbody{\tblrbody
      \category & \totalsum % <--- wrong locale // decimal
      \\
    }}%

% getting the sum of the total table
  \DTLsumcolumn{TotalStructuralMeasures}{totalsum}{\excSumTotalStructuralMeasures}
\begin{tblr}[%
  expand  = \tblrbody,
  long
  ]{%
    vspan=even,
    colspec = {%
      *{1}{X[4,m]}
      *{1}{X[c,si={table-format=6.0, round-mode=places, output-decimal-marker={,},locale=UK}]}
     %% *{1}{X[c,si={locale=UK}]}
    },
    hline{Y}={wd=1pt},
    column{2}={halign={c}},
    row{1}={guard}
  }
  Structural measures & Total Year\\
  \tblrbody
  Total & \excSumTotalStructuralMeasures \\
  \end{tblr}%
}
\NewDocumentCommand{\excFundingRequestTable}{}{%
  \begingroup%
  \def\tblrbody{}%
  \DTLforeach{\tmpLocalDB}{%
    \category=category,%
  \FundingYearOne   ={fundingYear1},%
  \FundingYearTwo   ={fundingYear2},%
  \FundingYearThree ={fundingYear3},%
  \FundingYearFour  ={fundingYear4},%
  \FundingYearFive  ={fundingYear5},%
  \FundingYearSix   ={fundingYear6},%
  \FundingYearSeven ={fundingYear7}%
}{%
    \protected@edef\tblrbody{\tblrbody
      \category
      & \FundingYearOne
      & \FundingYearTwo
      & \FundingYearThree
      & \FundingYearFour
      & \FundingYearFive
      & \FundingYearSix
      & \FundingYearSeven      \\
    }}%
\begin{tblr}[%
  expand  = \tblrbody,
  long
  ]{%
    vspan=even,
    colspec = {%
      *{1}{X[3,m]}
      *{7}{X[si={%
                   table-format=6,
                   table-auto-round,
                   round-mode=places},
                 c]}
             },
                 hline{2}={wd=0pt},
    hline{3}={wd=1pt},
    rowhead = 2,
    row{1,2}={guard},
    row{2} = {
      font={\bfseries},
      halign={c},
    }
  }
  % empty
  & Year 1
  & Year 2
  & Year 3
  & Year 4
  & Year 5
  & Year 6
  & Year 7 \\
    Funding category
  & \SetCell[c=7]{c}  Totals per year
  &
  &
  &
  &
  &
  &  \\
    \tblrbody
  \end{tblr}%
  \endgroup%
}

\makeatother

\NewDocumentCommand{\excTable}{om}{%
  % #1 value for a specific database
  % #2 using the default database of the defined table
\def\tmpLocalDB{#2}%
\IfStrEqCase{#2}{%
  {EarlyCareer}{\def\tmpLocalTableCaption{Funding Request for Early-career Support}\excFundingRequestTable}%
  {Collaboration}{\def\tmpLocalTableCaption{Funding Request for Collaboration with external partners}\excFundingRequestTable}%
}[\csname exc#2Table\endcsname]
}
\begin{document}

\excEntry{Collaboration}[funding]{
  category     = {Staff},
  fundingYear1 = {4119},
  fundingYear2 = {4229},
  fundingYear3 = {4339},
  fundingYear4 = {4449},
  fundingYear5 = {4559},
  fundingYear6 = {4669},
  fundingYear7 = {4779},
}
\excEntry{Collaboration}[funding]{
  category     = {{Direct project costs}},
  fundingYear1 = {5118},
  fundingYear2 = {5228},
  fundingYear3 = {5338},
  fundingYear4 = {5448},
  fundingYear5 = {5558},
  fundingYear6 = {5668},
  fundingYear7 = {5778},
}
\excEntry{EarlyCareer}[funding]{
  category     = {{Direct project costs}},
  fundingYear1 = {2000},
  fundingYear2 = {2000},
  fundingYear3 = {2000},
  fundingYear4 = {2000},
  fundingYear5 = {2000},
  fundingYear6 = {2000},
  fundingYear7 = {2000},
}
\excEntry{EarlyCareer}[funding]{
  category     = {Instrumentation},
  fundingYear1 = {3000},
  fundingYear2 = {3000},
  fundingYear3 = {3000},
  fundingYear4 = {3000},
  fundingYear5 = {3000},
  fundingYear6 = {3000},
  fundingYear7 = {3000},
}

% tables with correct decimals

\excTable{EarlyCareer}
\excTable{Collaboration}

% table with wrong decimals
\excTable{TotalStructuralMeasures}


% command with correct decimal
correct decimal: \excSumTotalStructuralMeasures

\end{document}
```

A visual product for better understanding:

[image]