# datatool and siunitx have different understanding of decimals and its conversion

Tags: siunitx, datatool

This is a follow up question on [Convert decimal to locale fails using datatool in combination with tabularray](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/708575/convert-decimal-to-locale-fails-using-datatool-in-combination-with-tabularray).
Or let’s say it this way: I could boil done the problem a lot.

The core problem is the different understanding of decimals by `datatool` and `siunitx`.
As soon as I use the command `\DTLsumforkeys` I get the `,` for a decimal marker, but `siunitx` uses a `dot`. Therefore I cannot use both together. When I try to use some conversions (e.g. `DTLdecimaltolocale`, `DTLsetnumberchars`) I fail as well.

I guess, when this is solved, I can also solve the problem at the question mentioned above.

I found out that with `\sisetup{output-decimal-marker={,}}` I can get the `,` for `siunitx` so the numbers by `datatool` and `siunitx` look the same but the comma should not be the decimal marker it should represent the "thousands-marker".

```
\documentclass[parskip=full]{scrartcl}
\begin{filecontents}{test.csv}
category,fundingYear1,fundingYear2,fundingYear3,fundingYear4,fundingYear5,fundingYear6,fundingYear7
Staff,4111,4222,4333,4444,4555,4666,4777
Direct project costs,7,6,5,4,3,2,1
Instrumentation,6111,6222,6333,6444,6555,6666,6777
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage{datatool,siunitx}


\DTLloaddb{ScienceCommunication}{test.csv}

\begin{document}
\DTLsumforkeys{ScienceCommunication}{%
      fundingYear1,%
      fundingYear2,%
      fundingYear3,%
      fundingYear4,%
      fundingYear5,%
      fundingYear6,%
      fundingYear7%
    }{\ScienceCommunication}

datatool: \ScienceCommunication\\
siunitx: \num{\ScienceCommunication}

conversion with datatool:\\
- \verb|DTLdecimaltolocale|:
\DTLdecimaltolocale{\ScienceCommunication}{\ScienceCommunicationOne}
\ScienceCommunicationOne


- \verb|\DTLsetnumberchars{.}{,}|:
\DTLsetnumberchars{.}{,}
\ScienceCommunication

- \verb|\DTLsetnumberchars{,}{.}|:
\DTLsetnumberchars{,}{.}
\ScienceCommunication

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: It looks to me like you want `input-decimal-markers ={.}, input-ignore={,}`, but i am not totally sure (i.e. treat `,` as a droppable spacing char) : can you confirm?

Comment: Yes, this solves the problem - also of the other question mentioned above. thanks. Such a small setting with huge impact.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set `,` to be treated as a spacing character (thus ignored) rather than a decimal marker

```latex
\sisetup{input-decimal-markers ={.}, input-ignore={,}}
```